# 3D point from two angles and a distance

Tags: math, 3d, opengl-es, geometry, opengl-es-2.0

I want to be able to calculate the coordinates of a 3D point, based on its distance from the origin, and two angles: "yaw" around Y-axis, and "pitch" around the X-axis.

In the example, distance from the origin would be 50 units, yaw 10 degrees, and pitch 10 degrees.

Is there a formula to retrieve the 3D result point?

[image: Graphic]

Comment: Seems you need to define your "angles" better. Yaw and pitch refers to orientation, not position.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Sorry if it was not clear.. I would say yaw is a rotation around the Y axis. But 0 degrees means looking at Z. Is it clearer now ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a point which is defined by an azimuth angle (`yaw`), an altitude angle (`pitch`) and a distance along this direction vector, then you have to transform the azimuth angle (`yaw`) and  altitude angle (`pitch`) to a unit direction vector first .
See [Solar zenith angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_zenith_angle), [Azimuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth) or [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles).

In an coordinate system, where the x axis points to the left and the z axis to the front and the y axis is the up vector ([Lefthanded coordiante system](http://www.f-lohmueller.de/pov_tut/a_geo/a_geo85e.htm)), this can be calculated as follows:

```
x = sin(yaw) * cos(pitch)
y = sin(pitch) 
z = cos(yaw) * cos(pitch)
```

where `yaw` is the clockwise angle between the z axis and the vector to the point (projected to the XZ plane).

This direction has to be multiplied b the distance to the origin:

```
P = distance * (x, y, z);
```

or

```
Px = distance * sin(yaw) * cos(pitch) 
Py = distance * sin(pitch) 
Pz = distance * cos(yaw) * cos(pitch)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this!  Wasn't a perfect match, but your explanation was excellent, and with a couple of adjustments for axis system I'm using it works perfectly!  Been searching for this for weeks!